# Composition of this cosmic material

Tags: science-based, magic, physics, strange-matter

In my story idea, there is a fluid material that also has many similarities to plasma. The strange matter (through means that I would also like to understand) converts regular forms of energy into something called cosmic energy, which (again, would like a realistic way of it doing this) causes things deemed improbable by quantum physics to happen. In short, one could do things like conjure fire or fly without breaking any natural laws, as long as they know how to use the 'loopholes.' It also distorts space-time, causing mirage like fields called transcendence fields, which exist in multiple areas of reality at once (so if it looks like an asteroid is flying towards you, get out of the field). This allowed intelligent 4D creatures to enter this dimension.

1  What would this plasmic matter be made of realistically?
2. How would this plasmic matter *realistically* convert energy into cosmic energy?
3. How would one ***realistically*** utilize this to achieve 'magical' things without defying quantum physics?

Comment: Huh... sounds like you are after some dimensional vibrating gluon-quark pudding, but... if any one here can answer this realistical, I wouldn't mind nominating him or her for the Nobel price of physics. At least. ;)

Comment: Welcome to the site Anonymia

Answer (score 10):

You want to make a new form of energy in space time (4D)? Then I have exactly what you need. Remember those lessons of radiation consisting of two fields, a magnetic and an electric field standing 90 degrees relative to each other?

[image: two fields]

Well, if we add the next dimension, we can have one more field standing 90 degrees on both of them. That is you 'cosmic energy'.

Creating this field is rather simple, analogous to how a generator works by moving a magnet through a magnetic field, you can have an object with 'cosmic magnetism' moving through a combination of an electric and a magnetic field.

This effect is caused by [particle spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_%28physics%29), a fundamental property that gets one more axis to spin about once we introduce 4D.

**Options:**

- Cosmic magnets can only be found naturally, and are extremely rare
- Cosmic magnets can only be provided by the 4D creatures.
- Cosmic magnets can be crafted, but only in the presence of a cosmic energy field. (Like normal permanent magnets are produced)

Your transcendence fields can be explained by the fact that the field only partly propagates through 3D space, causing local distortions of space time.

"Magical" effects can be produced by transmitting this energy to the place you want to use it, without the need for passing through the space in between, as the field only partly exists in 3D. ('fire' by just heating something with this wireless energy, of 'flying' by counteracting the gravitational pull of the Earth.)

Comment: +1 as this means the 'magic' effects aren't really magical at all, just obfuscated from our puny 3D minds.

Comment: I'm a proponent that the 4th dimension is time. Because while alive we can only move in one direction doesn't mean it stays that way when we die... Anyway, it's kind of hard to exist for zero time.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon If you prefer the notation of "time is a dimension too", I can clarify that I mean 4 spatial dimensions.

Comment: Oh, don't worry about it. People can read the comments. I doubt it would really bother anyone that much anyway. (It auto corrected to boer anyone hat!)

Comment: @Hohmannfan - What do you mean by 'object with cosmic magnetism?' Are you referring to the strange matter (which I call cosmogen, but any better names would be appreciated) being what generates the cosmic energy, or _using_ the cosmogen to generate it? That third perpendicular 4d field you mentioned, I have decided to call an 'arcane field,' due to this mythos's idea of arcane simply being something you don't have the 4d+ knowledge to do.

Comment: Along with this was my idea to define certain 'magical' characters. A wizard is any intelligent life that, similarly to how our bodies contain and generate heat and electricity, also contain and generate either/both this cosmic energy and/or the cosmogen. A sorcerer is any intelligent life that can't naturally produce either, but learns to absorb and/or harness and use it, with human sorcerers losing a part of their sanity as a result of dipping into higher dimensions. A mage is anyone who has retained sanity (i.e. being taught by a sorcerer/wizard) and can only use this through arcane items.

Answer (score 1):

1. What would this plasmic matter be made of realistically?
   **Unobtanium**
2. How would this plasmic matter realistically convert energy into cosmic energy?
   **Magic**
3. How would one realistically utilize this to achieve 'magical' things without defying quantum physics?
   **Unobtanium**

What you have here is a great excuse for some [applied phlebotinum](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AppliedPhlebotinum) (TV Tropes warning). You are looking for a vaguely sciency-sounding explanation for magic.

The problem is that nothing in currently known science gives you anything like what you are looking for so the good news is that you can make whatever you like up. The bad news is that whatever you make up will have no scientific basis.

You can always take some current scientific theories (for example String Theory or Quantum Physics) and pull some buzzwords out of it but essentially that's all you're doing. Dressing up your magic in science-sounding words.

There's nothing wrong with that, Star Trek does it all the time, but you should be aware that it's what you are doing.