# Becoming a 'Sorcerer' through cosmic energy

Tags: science-based, magic

**Alert - If you have not read my previous question, ['*Composition of this cosmic material*'](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/35473/8579), then this won't make sense. Please read that one first.**

In a previous question I had asked, I asked for advice on a material that 'vectored' cosmic energy. Now I'm trying to figure out how to utilize this energy to turn a mere human into a 'battery' for the energy. Some machine or technique that would allow humans to use the cosmogen and its emissions to cause occurrences that partially defy the laws of nature.

Here is my original idea: A device highly similar to a faraday cage, wired onto a person's head, could absorb, trap, and attune to the cosmic energy extracted from the cosmogen, and cause the person's brain to start running on this 4D energy in the environment (i.e. outside the lab). In turn, their brainwaves would also contain the reality shifting energy and cause certain thoughts to become reality, provided that the thought was 'strong enough.'

Of course, that is my thought on how it might work, but I don't know if this is a reasonable concept, and would appreciate any better solutions to the problem.

Comment: "*Please read that one first.*" Then... maybe *linking to it* would be a good idea. If you want to reference a question, that's fine, but you should actually *reference* it.

Comment: A link has been edited in.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ah, sorry. I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: You would need a 4D Faraday cage too:)

Answer (score 1):

**So you need humans to absorb the energy, while other things does not?**

Then we must have a fundamental difference between living things and all the other stuff. Biologists should be now starting to think about how difficult that distinction is.

I decide to go with "the ability to reduce the local entropy". Life is ordered structures, so the cosmogen can interact with life in an ordered pattern, instead of dampening out in randomness.

Order can be used to amplify things like waves, a phenomenon called [resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance). This can be used to create a local wave top in an other-ways weak universal cosmogen field.

**Some interesting, but optional mechanics this allows for:**

- While a "sorcerer" can create a local maximum in the cosmogen, negative resonance will dampen the surrounding field, effectively draining it. A somewhat pseudo-scientific explanation of "mana".
- Cosmogen interacts with electromagnetic forces, and can therefore be stored by the use of magnetic fields or circuits, like in a [Penning trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penning_trap)
- The local wave top can be used as a lens to determine the direction of the cosmogenic energy. This can provide a basis for "mind controlled magic".